# Dynamic Image Targets - Augmented Reality (Vuforia)

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I just want to ask, is it possible to have dynamic image targets using Vuforia? I'm thinking of a process that's roughly like this: Take a picture then that photo will be used to be an image target. Is that possible? If yes, how? I only know downloading a set of image targets from the developer site (Target database) and just load them. By doing this, it will be kind of close to markerless tracking. Any idea would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Yes , search for "user defined targets", i have developed an app with this technology just like what you have wrote "Take a picture then that photo will be used to be an image target"